# Parsing/manipulating weirdly formated json array

Tags: javascript, regex, json, string, single-quotes

I have the following broken javascript json string

```
[ 'some string's', 'inside, array', 60.4, 10.3, '' ]
```

I would like to parse this broken json string, scraped from the script part of a web page, into a javascript array - but as you see it's not valid json. The strings are single quoted and can also have a single quotes inside the string. So i need to replace the single quotes surrounding the string items with double quotes, without changing the single quotes inside the string.

Any regex magicians out here?

Update:
The strings could also contain commas, and the items can also be numbers.

Tip:
Look for the pattern `', '` to separated string items might work.

Comment: The thing you are trying to do is not regex-solvable in general. That's because regular expressions do not work with nesting. You will need a proper parser for that (which might not be easy to implement) unless you have more info about the input. Like for example that it is always a flat list.

Comment: Change the code that is creating the JSON to add backslashes/escaping, or wrap them with double quotes.

Comment: I can not change how the content is created since i scraped the data from a web page.

Comment: Dude, you're definitely doing something wrong. The example you've shown us has at least two interpretations: either 1-element array or 2-elements array. I doubt any site could use such ambiguous representation.

Comment: @freakish Yeah it's weird. I'm a scraping a web page with a script tag, so the array is declared as a javascript array, but i'm parsing it as a string.. I'l look more into the data..

Comment: Show us the website source code and your scraping code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your "bad" JSON strings always start with `[ '` and end with `' ]`, we can first "trim" the string, and then split using `', '`.

```js
    var str = "[ 'some string's', 76, 'inside, array', '', 60.4, 10.3, '', 56 ]";
    str = str.replace(/^\[ | \]$/g, '')
    var re = /'(.*?)'(?=,|$)|(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?=,|$)/g; 
    var m;
    arr = [];
    
    while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
        if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
            re.lastIndex++;
        }
        if (m[1] != undefined) {
           arr.push(m[1]);
           document.getElementById("res").innerHTML += m[1] + "<br/>";
        }
        else
        {
           arr.push(m[2]);
           document.getElementById("res").innerHTML += m[2] + "<br/>";
        }
    }
    alert(arr);
```

```html
<div id="res"/>
```

However, mind that the best way to fix JSON is to fix it on the JSON provider's side. If you have more complicated JSON strings, this solution will need enhancing.

Comment: And what if `,` is part of the value? Actually now that I think about it this problem is not solvable at all. Have a look at the OP's example. How do we know that it is an array of 2 elements, not a 1-element array with `some string's', 'inside array` as a value? Ambiguity.

Comment: I have also found commas in some strings - and i can't change it because i scraped it from a web page..

Comment: Yes, in these cases there will be ambiguity. I only suggested a way for the current example. I agree it is generally unsolvable like that.

Comment: Maybe looking for the pattern ', ' to separated string items might work?

Comment: Please check. Again, if you have more complicated JSON, this still might fail.

Comment: Great work @stribizhev ! It almost works, but some elements are numbers as well, and often the last element is just an empty string. So the last string is concatenated with the numbers and the empty string. I'll add to the question.

Comment: @Erlend: What about my updated function? I think we should remove empty values. Let me know if you want to keep them.

Comment: @stribizhev I tried your updated function but the result is the same. In your example you have quoted the number when it should just be a number - see my example in the question. I would prefer to keep the empty string, so it matches with the other results, but it's not that important.

Comment: OK, I see. I am now trying to match all the values. Not efficient, but I guess it is working now.

Comment: Thank you so much @stribizhev, you truly are a regex wizard!

Comment: You are welcome. Please also consider upvoting if the answer was helpful.